# Buffered Reader in Bluetooth app giving garbled output

Tags: android

I have rewritten this code a hundred times. I have an hc05 on arduino that is sending this "@,PMGBP01,34,456," With a println, resulting in CR LF that the readline does seem to find, but i am getting things like "@@P,P,PMGBP01,34,456. Looking like there are remnants of previous messages being left in the buffer?

```
 void beginListenForData()
{
    final int index = 0;
    InputStreamReader mmReader = new InputStreamReader( mmInputStream );
    BufferedReader mmBufferedReader = new BufferedReader( mmReader );

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    stopWorker = false;
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()


    {
        public void run() {
            //byte[] packetBytes = new byte[100];
            int index = 0;
            byte[] packetBytes = new byte[100];
            int bytes = 0;
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) {
                try {
                    if (mmInputStream.available() > 15){
                        while(mmInputStream.read() != '@');
                        String aString = mmBufferedReader.readLine();
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    parsPacket(aString, aString.length());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
           }
        }
    });
    workerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: `while(mmInputStream.read()` You are reading from the inputstream and after that the buffered reader reads from the same stream. Wrong. Let only one read from the same stream. You only have to call readLine() to read the line. Remove the other stuff. If readLine() returns null the sever closed the connection.

Comment: The while(mmInputStream.read() != '@'); is to get rid of any garbage left. Since my messages always start with @ . The messages are comma delimited and use the split function to get the data.

Comment: I did figure out the problem, not with the above code. Was using a esp8266 board to send serial data to an hc05 Bluetooth module. The messages where suppose to be sent on 5 second intervals, but was sending at ~2.5 seconds. The esp had a different clock speed than the compiler thought it had. So the software serial baud rate was way off from what the hc05 was expecting.  Thanks much for commenting!